# TNS_ADMIN on network hidden shared folder

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am using Oracle Managed Data Access in .NET core and I am experiencing a trouble.

I pointed the TNS_ADMIN environment variable to a network hidden shared folder like this "ITU-PCDSNV280\d$\Temp\TNS"

When I try to open the connection, I receive the error ORA-12154.

If I access the folder by Windows Explorer, it works perfectly.

Anothers apps works well too.

If I use the TNS_ADMIN on a shared folder without $ (like \ITU-PCDSNV280\admin), it works well too.

I think the problem is the $ sharing. Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks

André

Comment: Maybe try a Symbolic Link, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Microsoft_Windows

Comment: If you have to provide a centralized tns alias resolution then [Oracle Internet Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/idm/internet-directory/12.2.1.3/oidag/understanding-concepts-and-architecture-oracle-internet-directory.html#GUID-1D3DFEF1-D9DC-4076-ACC8-592EEA43E272) might be an option for you. However, I think it makes only sense if you have many databases running.

Comment: It should work. Please try "tnsping <TNSALIAS> and look for which path the client picks up. On linux we use "strace sqlplus" for troubleshooting, maybe there is a similar tool on Windows now? Just make sure it works with sqlplus/sqlcl before trying to make it work with your apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and ran a support case with Oracle. The bug is supposed to be fixed in the 19.6.0 release of ODP.NET. Our problem was in the full .NET driver, but I assume it is fixed in .NET core as well.

I found no workaround, other than using a "visible" share (one without $ in the end).